# How to avoid tree conflicts when merging branches that were moved?

Tags: svn, merge

I have a repository that looks like this:

```
/a/trunk/Library
/a/branches/FeatureX/Library
/b/trunk/Application
/b/branches/FeatureX/Application
```

I want to rearrange this so that I have the Application and Library folders next to each other:

```
/a/trunk/Library
/a/trunk/Application
/a/branches/FeatureX/Library
/a/branches/FeatureX/Application
```

I tried to achieve this by simply "svn copy"-ing the "Application" folders. The problem I'm facing is that when I try to merge "FeatureX" into "trunk" later on, I get a tree conflict because "Application" was added in both trunk and the branch.

Is there a better way to do this?

(BTW i cannot merge "FeatureX" *before* copying "Application", this is just a test to see if it will be possible later on...)

Answer (score 0):

OPTION 1:  Merge the changes from trunk (aka /b/trunk/Application) to your /a/branches/FeatureX.  That should you give you an 'original' Application folder in the FeatureX branch.  Then do a delta merge taking /b/trunk/Application and /b/branches/FeatureX/Application and merging those changes to a working copy of /a/branches/FeatureX/Application.  That should allow you to then cleanly merge /a/branches/FeatureX to /a/trunk.

OPTION 2:  Don't svn copy /b/trunk/Application to /a/trunk.  Rather svn copy /b/branches/FeatureX/Application to /a/branches/FeatureX.  Then merge those changes to /a/trunk when you are ready.  If there are changes in /b/trunk/Application that are not in /b/branches/FeatureX/Application, you'll want to re-base that branch before doing the svn copy over to /a/branches/FeatureX.

Comment: In option 1, shouldn't it be "aka /b/trunk/Application"?

Comment: If I understand your solutions correctly, in both options the final layout is only achieved after merging "FeatureX" into "trunk" as the last step. But in my scenario, "FeatureX" will not be merged for weeks or months, while I would like to implement the new repository layout right now.

Answer (score 0):

OPTION 3:  Based upon your comment for the previous answer, try this.  Do a SVN copy of /b/trunk/Application to a/trunk/Application.  Do a tree merge of /a/trunk from the revision you created /a/branches/FeatureX with to the latest (more than likely HEAD) of /a/trunk that contains the Application directory and apply that against your working copy of /a/branches/FeatureX.  Commit those changes.  Now do another delta merge of /b/branches/FeatureX/Application to /a/branches/FeatureX/Application against your working copy of /a/branches/FeatureX/Application.  Commit those changes to the repository.  You should have all of the changes in /a/trunk that were in /b/trunk and all of the changes in /b/branches/FeatureX in the /a/branches/FeatureX and ready to be merged back to /a/trunk when you are ready.  However, you will loose the direct history of all commits from /b/branches/FeatureX/Application in /a/branches/FeatureX/Application.  You can still see the history from /b/branches in /a/branches with -g option with the svn log command.

Answer (score 0):

Do your svn copy to trunk only of "Application." Create a new branch from trunk: featurex2. Merge featurex to featurex2. Remove featurex its an attractive nussaince now.